# form action is another page(php code) how to validate the form and display error message in view page

Tags: php

Form validation in php when form action is another page (php code). How do I validate the form and display error message in view page?

**view page**

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="redirect.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
    <label for="name"><b>Name: </b></label>
    <input type="text"  name="name" id="name" >
<br>
    <label for="email"><b>Email: </b></label>
    <input type="text"  name="email" id="email" >
<br>
    <label for="email"><b>Project Type: </b></label>
    <input type="text"  name="projecttype" id="projecttype">
<br>
    <label for="email"><b>Project Description: </b></label>
    <input type="text"  name="pdescription" id="pdescription" >
<br>
    <label for="file"><b>File Upload: </b></label>
    <input type="file"  name="file"  id="file">
<br>
    <div class="clearfix">
      <input type="submit" name="submit1" id="submit1" value="submit1">
    </div>  
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**redirect.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])) 
{
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $projecttype=$_POST['projecttype'];
    $projectdetails=$_POST['pdescription'];
    $attachment=$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $tmp_name=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"upload/".$attachment);
    $query=mysql_query("insert into projectdetails(Customer_name,Customer_email,Customer_attachment,Customer_project_type,Customer_project_details) values('$name','$email','$attachment','$projecttype','$projectdetails')");
    if($query)
    {   
        header('Location: test2.php');      
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: use `java script validation`  for that or use `html 5 required validation`

Comment: Why not use [jQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) or use simply jquery to validate your form ?

Comment: You validate the data, store errors and the initial data in a session, redirect back to the form and display errors and repopulate the form from the session. Alternative, use Ajax to save the form.

Comment: @Bhargav...i need form validation in php

Comment: @Bhargav - Even if you validate the data using JS, you still need to validate it in the back end as well. _Never_ trust anything that comes from the front end.

Comment: so try to use `session` for store error message

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen.....i need form validation in php

Comment: @MagnusEriksson....give me one small example

Comment: do you have html and php code in same file redirect.php?

Comment: FYI you also need to validate the file-upload module. As it is now, anyone can upload even a trojan file

Comment: 1. **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. **You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: @Swathi You dont need to send another page for validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create simple demo for `name field required in php using session`

you can try this way

**`form.php`**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])){
        $name=$_SESSION['msg']['name'];
    }
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="redirect.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
    <label for="name"><b>Name: </b></label>
    <input type="text"  name="name" id="name" > <span style="color:red"><?php echo $name ?></span>
<br>
    <label for="email"><b>Email: </b></label>
    <input type="text"  name="email" id="email" >
<br>
    <label for="email"><b>Project Type: </b></label>
    <input type="text"  name="projecttype" id="projecttype">
<br>
    <label for="email"><b>Project Description: </b></label>
    <input type="text"  name="pdescription" id="pdescription" >
<br>
    <label for="file"><b>File Upload: </b></label>
    <input type="file"  name="file"  id="file">
<br>
    <div class="clearfix">
      <input type="submit" name="submit1" id="submit1" value="submit1">
    </div>  
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**`redirect.php`**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])) 
{

    $name=$_POST['name'];

    if(isset($name) && empty($name)){
        $_SESSION['msg']['name']="Name must be required!";
        header('location: form.php');  
        exit;
    }
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $projecttype=$_POST['projecttype'];
    $projectdetails=$_POST['pdescription'];
    $attachment=$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $tmp_name=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"upload/".$attachment);
    $query=mysql_query("insert into projectdetails(Customer_name,Customer_email,Customer_attachment,Customer_project_type,Customer_project_details) values('$name','$email','$attachment','$projecttype','$projectdetails')");
    if($query)
    {   
        header('Location: test2.php');      
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: @Bhargav....Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\multipleform\test2.php on line 12

Comment: but i have not code for `test2.php` so you made some mistake in test2.php page share test2.php page if possible

Comment: @Bhargav....just name is test2.php(form.php) remaining all things are same

Comment: <span style="color:red"><?php echo $name; ?></span>

Comment: you change `form.html` to `form.php` and add this code on top ` session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])){
        $name=$_SESSION['msg']['name'];
    }`

Comment: <?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])){
        $name=$_SESSION['msg']['name'];
  
    }
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="redirect.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
    <label for="name"><b>Name: </b></label>
    <input type="text"  name="name" id="name" >
 <span style="color:red"><?php echo $name; ?></span></form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @Bharagav...same thing only i done but values are inserting in to database

Comment: in my local code work properly i dont no why you have get error $name

Comment: @Bhargav...but one more thing how to unset the message after submit the form

Comment: You need to define `$name` before the if-statement. This code only defines `$name` if the session is set, but is always trying to echo it later on. That's why there's a `undefined variable` on the first load of the form.

Comment: you can clear the session or unset the session  for that like `unset($_SESSION['msg']`

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that the simple way I would suggest to use HTML5

```js
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

$(function () {
        $('form').bind('click', function (event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'post.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
              alert('form was submitted');
            }
          });

        });
      });
```

```html
    <html>
    <body>
    <form action="redirect.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
        <label for="name"><b>Name: </b></label>
        <input type="text"  name="name" id="name" required>
    <br>
        <label for="email"><b>Email: </b></label>
        <input type="email"  name="email" id="email" required>
    <br>
        <label for="email"><b>Project Type: </b></label>
        <input type="text"  name="projecttype" id="projecttype" required>
    <br>
        <label for="email"><b>Project Description: </b></label>
        <input type="text"  name="pdescription" id="pdescription" required>
    <br>
        <label for="file"><b>File Upload: </b></label>
        <input type="file"  name="file"  id="file" required>
    <br>
        <div class="clearfix">
          <input type="submit" name="submit1" id="submit1" value="submit1">
        </div>  
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

In PHP PAge :

```
if(empty($_POST['name'])){
 echo "Name is required";
}
```

Comment: This is far from enough to validate user inputs. Anyone can easily just bypass the form altogether and post directly to the action or even modify the HTML using "Inspect code" and remove any "required" or typed fields. Never ever trust data that comes from the front end.

Comment: you'll be better off with server-side validation

Answer (score 0):

Set errors in a session before redirecting, echo them on the view page then unset the errors at the top of redirect.php, by unsetting them at the top you will make sure you always have the most recent error messages.

Answer (score 0):

**Severe issue in your code**

1. [Do not use mysql_* functions in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

**Fine tuning that can be done in your code**

1. You don't need to send your input to another page just for validation

**Some examples for you**

[Client Side form Validation](http://jsfiddle.net/5zqW7/)

[PHP MySQLi Basic Examples](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.examples-basic.php)

**If you need to proceed in your current implementation**

Declare a variable called as `$formavalid` and make it true and false accordingly

```
<html>
<body>
<?php 
$formvalid = true;
?>
<form action="redirect.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
    <label for="name"><b>Name: </b></label>
    <input type="text"  name="name" id="name" >
<br>
    <label for="email"><b>Email: </b></label>
    <input type="text"  name="email" id="email" >
<?php
//Do like this for all fields
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])) 
{
if(!isset($_POST['email'])) 
{
echo 'Email field is missing';
}else{
$formvalid = false;// Make the $formvalid as false if your input is dirty
}
}
<br>
    <label for="email"><b>Project Type: </b></label>
    <input type="text"  name="projecttype" id="projecttype">
<br>
    <label for="email"><b>Project Description: </b></label>
    <input type="text"  name="pdescription" id="pdescription" >
<br>
    <label for="file"><b>File Upload: </b></label>
    <input type="file"  name="file"  id="file">
<br>
    <div class="clearfix">
      <input type="submit" name="submit1" id="submit1" value="submit1">
    </div>  
</form>
<?php
if($formvalid==true){
//Form is valid so do the action for it
}else{
//form is not valid, so let the user input to make it valid
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope, this helps you

Comment: If you look at the question, I think the OP wants to redirect back to the form page (the form is on another page) and show the errors there.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Ahm, then it should be check and send back to display

Comment: Jupp. flash sessions for the errors and post data (to repopulate the form).

Comment: Obviously, I think the better approach will be form validation from client side using jquery and then do validation on server side too (for safe zone)

Comment: I totally agree. I even think it's a better solution to just use Ajax to validate/save the form. Maybe have two steps. First validate the oridnary inputs, then post the form (no need to send the file when validating the text). Then save it using Ajax (and do the same validation, for security but this time, send the file as well). Specially since it include file uploads. Nicer to have a spinner/progress bar than a blocking HTTP request.

Comment: Yeah, that's the universal way. Modifying the answer to tell the better way to handle